# how do I ungray network icon in task bar

Tags: windows-7

I am running Windows 7 Professional 64bit and I would like to get the network icon in my taskbar.  I go to Control Panel->Notification Area Icons->System Icons and I see the Network system icon has a toggle box that switches between ON/OFF.  This toggle box is greyed out and I cannot use it.  How do I fix this so I can turn this on?  Thanks.

Edit:
I had another user log onto this computer and their network icon appears in the task bar.  I am the only user that does not have this icon or the ability to turn it on and off.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Start / Run / gpedit.msc`
2. Navigate to `User Configuration / Administrative Templates / Start Menu and Taskbar`:

   [image]
3. In the right pane, double-click the `Remove the networking icon` option and set it to either `Not Configured` or `Disabled`:

   [image]
4. Log off and log back on or reboot if required
5. Now trying turning on the icon

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the pics!  I tried this but no luck :(

Comment: This is known as the "Local Group Policy Editor", FYI.

Comment: @Wingman4l7: Yes, I know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected to some network? Try ticking the option "Show all the icons and the notification on the task bar" that is on the bottom of the window...

Comment: I tried this and it expanded the task bar icons to show everything except the network icon.  When I do this it is still greyed out.  I cannot see any greyed out icons at all.